# Can't clip the image (css)

Tags: css

I have an image which I would like to crop using style.clip

```
<div><img src="someimage.jpg" style=" z-index:1000; width:200px; height:200px; position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px; clip:rect(30px 15px 30px 15px); overflow:hidden;" id="zoom1"/></div>
```

but it doesn't work. The image just disappears.

Why doesn't it crop the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape you are applying is `0px width, 0px height`

The clip applies:

```
rect(<top>, <right>, <bottom>, <left>)
```

As you have the top and the bottom equal as well as the left and the right equal then there are no pixels to display.

Your cut goes from:

```
Horizontally: 15px to 15px == 0px to display
Vertically: 35px to 35px == 0px to display
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip)

Comment: It doesn't matter. Even if I change the Right and Bottom values to say 5px and 3px respectively, it won't work.

Comment: are you sure your wrapper div is displaying?

Comment: I've just set 
     <div style=" width:200px; height:200px; border:1px #993300 solid">
...
</div>
but it didn't work.

Comment: @user1190478,  `right` and `bottom` values in `clip` notation are counted not from right and bottom edges of the element, but from its *left* and *top* edges, respectively: see the picture [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-clip).

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `;` after `hidden`

And this is your missing ingredient:

```
display: block;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6XGV3/

Comment: in my chrome if you remove the display block in that fiddle it also works, the issue seems to be elsewhere.

Comment: I have tried applying display:block before, but with no success.
Comma is irrelevant.

Comment: It also subsequently worked for me moving the absolute positining to the parent div. Aside from both of these suggestions, I'm afraid i'm stumped

Comment: I've tried that one before as well.
It will show the image, but won't crop.
The image which is being cropped should be positioned absolutely, thus removing absolute positioning from the image and setting it to the parent div doesn't work.

Comment: `display: block` is not necessary for absolutely positioned normally inline element, it's implied: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo

Answer (score 0):

According to the [clip property syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp) you missed the commas between the coordinates.